# Fast processing

Tags: python, igraph

In python and igraph I have many nodes with high degree. I always need to consider the edges from a node in order of their weight. It is slow to sort the edges each time I visit the same node. Is there some way to persuade igraph to always give the edges from a node in weight sorted order, perhaps by some preprocessing?

Comment: I am not sure if there is an easy and fast way to do this. Maybe you could just use an adjacency list data type with right sorting, instead of an igraph graph. You can convert between the two in O(n+m).

Comment: @GaborCsardi I think this might be a good solution. However, in pure python I worry this will be very space inefficient and my graph is large. This is unless there is some way of doing it in numpy/scipy that is better.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you wont have access to the C backend from Python. What about storing the sorted edge in an attribute of the vertices eg in `g.vs["sortedOutEdges"]` ?

Comment: That would work but hugely increases the memory needed sadly. My graphs are large.

Comment: You probably should ask the igraph developpers.